# Filter referenced item without losing other content

Tags: 7, entities, views

I have 2 entity types Content type A and B.
Content type B has a date field and an entity reference to A.

I need a view that shows all the nodes of content type A
But also shows all the referenced content, until this point I have no problem.

The only problem is that the content type B needs a filter to only show the content from this year. But when I add a filter to the date field all the nodes that don't have an entity reference also get filtered out.

Content type A are assets

Fields:

- Title
- Address
- lat/long

Content type B is the maintenance of these assets

Fields:

- Title
- Entity reference to A
- date field

Now I want to show all the assets in a view.( also the ones that don't have maintenance done)
In the same view there should be a column with all the maintenance within a certain timespan.

When I have this view i can put these on a google map and show which assets need maintenance and which are already done

Comment: Did you check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbNTRMRBdvo)?

Comment: I already know how to add a date filter. The problem is that all the nodes of type a without an entity reference also get filtered out.

Comment: Did you add any [entity reference relationship](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPQZLt3LHTY) in views?

Comment: Yes the entity reference from B to A otherwise I cant show fields from the content type B

Comment: You question is a bit confusing so could you please update your question and mention the ultimate output you want. And please attached screenshot if you can.

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what I understand your needs its very simple.

You have to set the filter criteria in the views:

1. Add Content Type **A**
2. Add Content Type **B**
3. Add Published field **twice**
4. Add Date Field and set its criteria as **you already set**
5. The field (Entity Reference field in Type B) that reference to Type A and set its operator as **Is not empty (NOT NULL)**
6. Now, **Open** re-arrange the filter criteria fields

[image]
 7. You need to **Create new filter group** under the filter criteria and drag drop your fields in required group like below

[image]

I hope this will at least give you an idea how to filter different content types with different field(s).

Thanks